# How to Load multiple SegmentedControl into a ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to load multiple SegmentedControls into one ViewController on Xcode. Below are the buttons. 
[image: Buttons]

When I click on one of the buttons, I want the SegmentedControl to load.
[image: SegmentedControl]

These SegmentedControls will load onto a ViewController. Is there any way to make that happen?

My current code is similar to below:

```
    @IBAction func action(_ sender: Any) {

    //let url = URL(string: sender.accessibilityIdentifier!)!

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: (sender as AnyObject).accessibilityLabel, message: (sender as AnyObject).accessibilityHint, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let HSAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Upper Building", style: .default) { action in

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "one", sender: nil)
        }


        //UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
    alertController.addAction(HSAction)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After moving to the other view controller, you can create segmentedcontrol with multiple buttons, like below.

```
segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl (items: ["First","Second","Third"])
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(60, 250,200, 30)
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: "segmentedControlAction:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    self.view.addSubview(segmentedControl)
```